Error "Subscriptions should use wsLink" using tRPC
While trying to implement subscriptions with tRPC, I encountered this issue, that it should use wsLink, even though, it is implemented in the trpc client.
I get this error when trying to use randomNumber router, here is my code:
This is my wssDevServer.ts file
/src/server/wssDevServer.ts

const wss = new ws.Server({
  port: 3001
})
const handler = applyWSSHandler({
  wss,
  router: appRouter,
  createContext,
  // Enable heartbeat messages to keep connection open (disabled by default)
  keepAlive: {
    enabled: true,
    // server ping message interval in milliseconds
    pingMs: 30000,
    // connection is terminated if pong message is not received in this many milliseconds
    pongWaitMs: 5000
  }
})

wss.on('connection', ws => {
  console.log(`➕➕ Connection (${wss.clients.size})`)
  ws.once('close', () => {
    console.log(`➖➖ Connection (${wss.clients.size})`)
  })
})
console.log('✅ WebSocket Server listening on ws://localhost:3001')

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.log('SIGTERM')
  handler.broadcastReconnectNotification()
  wss.close()
})

This is my trpc client:
//utils/trpc.ts

// const { publicRuntimeConfig } = getConfig()

// const { APP_URL, WS_URL } = publicRuntimeConfig

function getEndingLink(ctx: NextPageContext | undefined): TRPCLink<AppRouter> {
  if (typeof window === 'undefined') {
    return httpBatchLink({
      /**
       * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/data-transformers
       */
      transformer: superjson,
      url: `http://localhost:3000/api/trpc`,
      headers() {
        if (!ctx?.req?.headers) {
          return {}
        }
        // on ssr, forward client's headers to the server
        return {
          ...ctx.req.headers,
          'x-ssr': '1'
        }
      }
    })
  }
  const client = createWSClient({
    url: 'ws://localhost:300'
  })
  return wsLink({
    client,
    /**
     * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/data-transformers
     */
    transformer: superjson
  })
}

/**
 * A set of strongly-typed React hooks from your `AppRouter` type signature with `createReactQueryHooks`.
 * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/react#3-create-trpc-hooks
 */
export const trpc = createTRPCNext<AppRouter>({
  /**
   * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/ssr
   */
  ssr: true,
  ssrPrepass,
  config({ ctx }) {
    /**
     * If you want to use SSR, you need to use the server's full URL
     * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/ssr
     */

    return {
      /**
       * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/client/links
       */
      links: [
        // adds pretty logs to your console in development and logs errors in production
        loggerLink({
          enabled: opts =>
            (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' && typeof window !== 'undefined') ||
            (opts.direction === 'down' && opts.result instanceof Error)
        }),
        getEndingLink(ctx)
      ],
      /**
       * @link https://tanstack.com/query/v5/docs/reference/QueryClient
       */
      queryClientConfig: { defaultOptions: { queries: { staleTime: 60 } } }
    }
  },
  /**
   * @link https://trpc.io/docs/v11/data-transformers
   */
  transformer: superjson
})

// export const transformer = superjson;
/**
 * This is a helper method to infer the output of a query resolver
 * @example type HelloOutput = RouterOutputs['hello']
 */
export type RouterOutputs = inferRouterOutputs<AppRouter>

Note that i launch the wssDevServer with this command:
cross-env PORT=3001 tsx watch src/server/wssDevServer.ts --tsconfig tsconfig.server.json 
In my appRouter, I have this procedure:
 randomNumber: publicProcedure.subscription(() => {
    return observable<number>(emit => {
      const int = setInterval(() => {
        emit.next(Math.random())
      }, 500)
      return () => {
        clearInterval(int)
      }
    })
  }),

Which causes the Error "Subscriptions should use wsLink" using tRPC, any suggestions to solve this issue? Thanks.
